# What movie has earth’s atmosphere depleted, and spaceships that look like winged bubbles?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m looking for a movie that involves a depleted earth's atmosphere.

In the beginning of the movie, there is a space battle in orbit with odd-looking spaceships that look like bubbles with wings. The pilots (two ships) have crosshairs in one of their eyes.

The atmosphere itself is thin, forcing people to stay inside or get sun poisoning.

Sorry, that's all I can remember.

Comment: The space battle portion sounds similar to how the big screen adapataion of Lost In Space starts right down to the pilots wearing contacts that have their targeting reticules on them, however I believe the premise of the need to leave the planet has to do with depleated resources and not the atmosphere.

Comment: I'd back that as being the answer. The IMDB entry for Lost In Space lists "pollution and global warming" as being the reason for the Jupiter mission. I can't comment on the "people staying in" part - I'd have to rewatch it to find out for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is looking more and more like Lost in Space (1998)

From the transcript

> Imagine an end to world hunger. What if ample food and clean drinking water were the birthright of all our planet's children?
>
> **GENERAL:** Major, you are aware Earth's resources are severely limited.
> **WEST:** Every schoolchild knows our recycling technologies will save the environment. Sending a family across the galaxy is a publicity stunt to sell soda to people of all ages.
> **GENERAL:** What I am about to tell you is classified. Every schoolchild has been lied to. The recycling technologies have failed. In less than two decades Earth will be unable to support human life.

Oddly enough, Lost in Space is available on Youtube in German.